# RSPEC not working with RVM

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I just installed rvm, and got it working all nice and pretty. I was previously running ruby 1.8.7 and it was preventing a couple of my rspec tests from passing.

Now that I have rvm installed and working properly my rspec is not working. I know I have the rspec gem installed. But now when run the `rake`command I get this error when running ruby 1.9.2:

```
(in /Users/TheRedFool/learn_ruby-master)
rake aborted!
Could not find rspec (~> 2) amongst [bundler-1.3.2, minitest-1.6.0, rake-10.0.3, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8, rubygems-bundler-1.1.1, rvm-1.11.3.6]
/Users/TheRedFool/learn_ruby-master/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/TheRedFool/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/TheRedFool/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

And when using the `rake` command while running ruby 2.0.0 I get this error:

```
(in /Users/TheRedFool/learn_ruby-master)
rake aborted!
Could not find 'rspec' (~> 2) among 8 total gem(s)
/Users/TheRedFool/learn_ruby-master/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is driving me a little bonkers, so thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: run `gem install rspec` while running your `ruby 2.0.0` installation so it updates the rspec gem to the proper version, if your project is using bundler then just do `bundler install`.

Comment: Thanks @fmendez when I run the install for the rspec gem I get this error: ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use `rvm` and install a new ruby version you must install a new set of gems either in a `gemset` or the default gemset. They don't get passed along versions, specially ones that weren't installed with rvm. You can check to see if you have the gem installed by running

`gem list | grep rspec`

Also, note that if your project has a Gemfile you can run `bundle install` to install to make sure all your gems are installed where they belong.

Comment: +1. I'll just add to this that I've had problems with Bundler v1.3 when running Ruby 1.9.x, so I'd advise installing Bundler v1.2 for that and 1.3 for Ruby 2.x.

Comment: Yepp, this was the answer. Thanks @Leo Correa. The root of the problem I think was that I was trying to run it using ruby 2.0.0, and the rspec gem would not install on that version for some reason. When I switched the rvm default to 1.9.2 the gem installed and now it's working fine.